# CREATE operation not permitted

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, icloud, cloudkit

I am trying to utilize `CloudKit` in my iOS application, but when I attempt to create a new record for for a `User` record type (record type is named `Users`), I get this error:

```
<CKError 0x7fb80947ffb0: "Permission Failure" (10/2007);
server message = "CREATE operation not permitted";
uuid = 8C4C7B60-E3F4-42FC-9551-D3A76A6FF9D6;
container ID = "iCloud.com.jojodmo.Blix">
```

To create the new record, I am using this code in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
UserCKManager.create(
    CloudKitUser(
        email: "email@website.com", password: "password", salt: "1AF4E759B20FEC32",
        username: "jojodmo", posts: [], biography: "This is my bio",
        firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", flags: [],
        profilePicture: UIImage(), downVotesGiven: 1, downVotesRecieved: 2,
        upVotesGiven: 3, upVotesRecieved: 4, pictureProvided: false), callback: nil)
```

Which creates a new `CloudKitUser`:

```
init(email: String, password: String, salt: String, username: String, posts: [String], biography: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, flags: [String], profilePicture: UIImage, downVotesGiven: Int, downVotesRecieved: Int, upVotesGiven: Int, upVotesRecieved: Int, pictureProvided: Bool){ 
    self.ready = false
    record = CKRecord(recordType: "Users")
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
    self.salt = salt
    self.username = username
    self.posts = posts
    self.biography = biography
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.flags = flags
    self.profilePicture = profilePicture
    self.downVotesGiven = downVotesGiven
    self.downVotesRecieved = downVotesRecieved
    self.upVotesGiven = upVotesGiven
    self.upVotesRecieved = upVotesRecieved
    self.pictureProvided = pictureProvided
    self.ready = true
}
```

And then attempts to create a record with it:

```
class func create(user: User, callback: ((success: Bool, user: User?) -> ())?){
    let ckUser = CloudKitUser(user: user)
    //I've also tried using CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase, and I get the same error
    CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.saveRecord(ckUser.record){(record, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            println("An error occurred: \(error)")
            callback?(success: false, user: nil)
        }
        else{
            println("Record saved successfully")
            callback?(success: true, user: ckUser)
        }
    }
}
```

I know it isn't a problem with connecting to the database, because I have already gotten an error saying that there was no container with the ID I had given, which I fixed.

I am trying to run this on the `iOS` simulator (I am signed into iCloud on it)

Comment: This seems to be a permission problem. Can you access the database directly with the same user? If so, can you create your record with direct access? I believe the answer for the first is yes and for the second is no. You need to give the database user create permission.

Comment: @LajosArpad The first answer IS yes, but the second answer IS also no, how can I give the database user create permission? I feel like I would have tried that if I knew how

Comment: Possible answer could be setting the create permissions described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56733008/1807644

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users is a special recordType that already exist in CloudKit. You should not create records yourself. Records will be automatically created for new users that are using your app. 
You also can't create subscriptions and query the Users recordtype. You can only query Users records directly by ID. You can store extra data in the Users recordType, but I think in your case it would be better if you named your record type something else.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to get the id of the currnet user, so I can query for their password and username?

Comment: The current iCloud user will only have an id, firstname and lastname. You could add your own password field, but why should your user login twice? its already loged in into iCloud. You can get your id using the fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler on the container.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Edwin's answer, it's entirely feasible to save custom fields to the **public** `Users` recordType, but you need to retrieve the `CKRecordID` for the user first (via `CKContainer` `fetchUserRecordID()` or `discoverUserIdentity()`) and then build the `CKRecord` on `Users` using that ID.

Also, if you're using `CKModifyRecordsOperation` make sure the `savePolicy` is set to `.changedKeys` in order to allow the update to go through.