# Swift saving new comments using CloudKit

Tags: swift, database, server, nspredicate, cloudkit

I'm trying to make an app which stores a user's comment on CloudKit and then  shows it to the other users. User simply enters his/her comment on a text field and clicks on a submit button to submit his/her comment (just like a restaurant app). However, I can't seem to find the correct way no matter what I try. Here is my code, I'd be very glad for any help as I've been stuck on this problem for some time now. Thank you very much in advance!

```
@IBAction func OnSubmitTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (textField.text != ""){

        let newComment = CKRecord(recordType: "Users")
        let publicDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
        newComment.setValue(textField.text!, forKey: "comment")
        publicDB.save(newComment){
            rec ,err in
            if let error = err {

            print(err.debugDescription)
            return
            }

            publicDB.fetch(withRecordID: newComment.recordID){
                rec, err in

                print(rec!["comment"]!)
                return
            }
        }
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "comment", predicate: predicate)
        let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

        var commentRecords: [CKRecord] = []

        operation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
            commentRecords.append(record)
        }

        operation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
            print(commentRecords)
        }

        CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.add(operation)
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting errors? What is not working as expected?

Comment: @Chris I get this error:Optional(<CKError 0x60400044f6f0: "Permission Failure" (10/2007); server message = "CREATE operation not permitted"; uuid = 4BCB3DF8-80F3-4862-A80D-04C55E9AA3AA; container ID

Comment: @EgeBerkAkkaya Can you fetch changes in the dashboard for the specific zone, database and development-container version if you start with an empty `Fetch record changes since`-field?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a permission error because `Users` is a protected record type that CloudKit creates automatically for users of your app. You should name it something else and then it should work.

For example, you could make a `Comment` record type. This might need a field that references the current user. You can get the current userID with:

`CKContainer fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:`

Here is the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKContainer/fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:) for this method.

It is also possible to use the `Users` record type, but you would have to find the existing userID from CloudKit as above then build a record around that.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27564272/8289095).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! I don't get any errors now during the debugging process and XCode successfully prints the comment I entered. However, nothing seems to appear on my dashboard in my newly created record. How can I fix this issue?? Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Are you querying for your new record type in the dashboard rather than users?

Comment: Both Users and NewUsers (my other record type) give me this error in the dashboard: There was a problem querying the “Users” (or "NewUsers") type.
Field 'recordName' is not marked queryable. Enable the “queryable” index on this field in the indexes section. However I double checked and everything is already set as queryable, searchable and sortable.

Comment: Hmm I’m not sure. I’ll have a look when I’m back at my computer.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending your time

Comment: @EgeBerkAkkaya I’m afraid I cannot find an answer, other than making sure everything is set ok in dashboard. [This question on Apple forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79126) seemed promising but the only answer may not be useful.